# Why using a 0 value resistor

Tags: pcb, resistors

In this schematic example they are using a 0 value resistor for R3 on the right side. Why should I do that?

[image]

Is this only because of the TP? As I dropped the TP for my design I would think of dropping the 0 resistor also.

[Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slvuab6/slvuab6.pdf)

Comment: 0 ohm resistors are used for a variety of reasons, sometimes as a jumper to avoid adding layers or vias to circuitboards, sometimes for an optional connection, sometimes because a robot might be more easily loaded with these than wire jumpers.  For design purposes you can probably ignore it and just remember that it was there.

Comment: In this case, it gives the option of using TP6, whatever that is, some voltage sensor, and if it was being used, you would switch out the 0 ohm resistor for a larger one to add tp6 to the voltage divider.

Comment: You didn't link the datasheet that the schematic came from and [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps563219.pdf) doesn't have that schematic. Can you update your question with the link?

Comment: @Transistor I've just added the datasheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a zero-ohm resistor isn't unusual but to position TP6 at its junction with R1 is.

My first thoughts were that it would allow adjustment of V<sub>OUT</sub> and, perhaps, late customisation of boards for different output voltages by adding R3 > 0 to attenuate V<sub>FB</sub>. This isn't supported by the datasheet, however, as Table 4 lists TP6 as "V<sub>OUT</sub> positive monitor point" and, in that case, why not use TP7.

The board is double-sided so it doesn't provide and jumper function. Being SMD it doesn't provide any useful hook-on point and the TP is there anyway.

My guess is that is a strange design feature carried over from another product but unused here.

Answer (score 1):

People use zero ohm resistors for several reasons: -

- To act as a bridge to isolate ground planes or power planes.
- To preserve the ability to insert a non-zero-ohm resistor should optimization of some parameter be required.
- To ensure that a test point is positioned electrically where it ought to be.
- Unused digital input pins instead of terminated directly to ground are often connected via a resistor or zero-ohm-link so that if needed there is some copper with which to make a wire connection to.

There are probably other reasons too. Take your pick.